# Terminology for functions with $F(a,a,\dots,a) = a$

Tags: functions, terminology

Is there a commonly used terminology for functions $F : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

> if $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x_i = a$ for all $i\in \{1,\dots, n\}$, $F(x) = a$

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In universal algebra, such functions are called *idempotent*. Typical usage is for a binary operation: for example the meet in a lattice is idempotent: $x ∧ x = x$ for every $x$.